# Avg # of Rectangle Intersections in 2D Field

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics

So imagine I have a large 2D field. Thousands of small rectangles overlay the field. The field is much larger than the rectangles. The rectangles are placed randomly in the field such that they may or may not overlap.

If I sample a particular x,y location in the field, I may intercept 0, 1, 2, or more of the small rectangles (i.e. the x,y point would lie inside some integer number of rectangles). My primary goal is to figure out the average number of rectangles that are sampled per x,y location. (i.e. on average I intersect 2.5 rectangles per sample).

I know what the size of the field is (say 1 km square) and what the size of the rectangles (say 1 m square) are. I do not know how many rectangles are in the field, although I have some idea that there would be on the order of thousands to tens of thousands of rectangles in the field

In an ideal world I would take many samples and calculate an average. But here, making these samples is very expensive. Thus, I wish to make as few samples as possible in order to estimate the average number (and standard deviation) of intersections per sample location. Obviously as the number of sample locations increases, the uncertainty in the mean decreases.

I have written computer code to perform a simulation study to calculate a result, but I am not that happy with the results, which show that the average number of intersections is highly uncertain. I would like another way to verify my results.

**I am wondering if it is possible to analytically derive the mean and standard deviation of the number of intersections for $m$ sample locations, for $n$ rectangles with a field that is $D_x$ by $D_y$ in extents.**

Answer (score 0):

Compute the overlay (set of distinct intersection regions where a unique combination of rectangles intersect) of all your rectangles. The complexity of the overlay could be quadratic in the number of rectangles, but no higher. Each distinct region in the overlay will be a polygon whose area you can compute by triangulating and computing the area of the triangles. (linear time in the complexity of the overlay). Then, each polygon has a count of how many rectangles overlap to form the polygon. Your random variable (number of rectangles hit by a random point) takes on value $k$ with probability proportional to the sum of all polygon areas that are defined by an intersection of exactly $k$ rectangles. Your random variable takes on value 0 with probability proportional to the total region size minus the total areas of all the polygon regions occupied by rectangles. So it's a discrete distribution, and once you calculate the probabilities you can easily get mean and standard deviation.